# PostgreSQL Query Optimization: Avoiding Sequential Scan on Messages Table

Tags: postgresql

**Problem:**

I have a PostgreSQL query that retrieves messages between two users from a "Messages" table. However, the query is performing a sequential scan on the table, and I'm looking for ways to optimize it.

```
explain SELECT t."Id", t."Content", t."ConversationId", t."CreatedAt", t."IsReadByRecipient", t."ReadAt", t."RecipientId", t."SenderId"
FROM (
    SELECT m."Id", m."Content", m."ConversationId", m."CreatedAt", m."IsReadByRecipient", m."ReadAt", m."RecipientId", m."SenderId"
    FROM "Messages" AS m
    WHERE (m."SenderId" = 15 AND m."RecipientId" = 1) OR (m."RecipientId" = 15 AND m."SenderId" = 1)
    LIMIT 100
) AS t
ORDER BY t."CreatedAt";
";
```

I currently have the following indexes on the "Messages" table:

```
PK_Messages
IX_Messages_CreatedAt
IX_Messages_RecipientId
IX_Messages_SenderId
```

Additional Information:

The table has a significant number of rows.
I've already tried creating a composite index on ("SenderId", "RecipientId", "CreatedAt") but didn't see the desired improvement.

my query plan is like this  :

```
Sort  (cost=194.13..194.38 rows=100 width=88)
"  Sort Key: m.""CreatedAt"""
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..190.80 rows=100 width=88)
"        ->  Seq Scan on ""Messages"" m  (cost=0.00..36001.04 rows=18868 width=88)"
"              Filter: (((""SenderId"" = 15) AND (""RecipientId"" = 1)) OR ((""RecipientId"" = 15) AND (""SenderId"" = 1)))"
```

What other index strategies can I try to optimize this query and avoid the sequential scan?
Are there any other factors that might be contributing to the suboptimal performance?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for this statement? (in plain text, as an update of your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example dataset...

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE msg( sender INTEGER NOT NULL, receiver INTEGER NOT NULL, date INTEGER NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO msg SELECT random()*1000, random()*1000, n FROM generate_series(1,10000000) n;
INSERT INTO msg SELECT 1001, 1002, n FROM generate_series(1,100000) n;
VACUUM ANALYZE msg;
CREATE INDEX msg_sr ON msg(sender,receiver);
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM msg WHERE sender=1 AND receiver=15 OR sender=15 AND receiver=1;
 Bitmap Heap Scan on msg  (cost=9.08..88.33 rows=20 width=12) (actual time=0.060..0.106 rows=16 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((sender = 1) AND (receiver = 15)) OR ((sender = 15) AND (receiver = 1)))
   Heap Blocks: exact=16
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=9.08..9.08 rows=20 width=0) (actual time=0.044..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on msg_sr  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=7 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((sender = 1) AND (receiver = 15))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on msg_sr  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=9 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((sender = 15) AND (receiver = 1))
 Execution Time: 0.164 ms

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM msg WHERE sender=1001 AND receiver=1002 OR sender=1002 AND receiver=1001;
 Bitmap Heap Scan on msg  (cost=25.65..4329.59 rows=1217 width=12) (actual time=8.202..30.576 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((sender = 1001) AND (receiver = 1002)) OR ((sender = 1002) AND (receiver = 1001)))
   Heap Blocks: exact=541
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=25.65..25.65 rows=1217 width=0) (actual time=7.957..7.958 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on msg_sr  (cost=0.00..20.50 rows=1207 width=0) (actual time=7.947..7.947 rows=100000 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((sender = 1001) AND (receiver = 1002))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on msg_sr  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((sender = 1002) AND (receiver = 1001))
 Execution Time: 38.251 ms
```

In both cases, with the multicolumn index, the plan is optimal.

If you get a seq scan, then either the table wasn't ANALYZED, or your table contains mostly messages between users 1 and 15. If most of the table will satisfy the select criteria, then there's no point in using the index, it would only slow it down. So postgres uses a seq scan. When you use test data to profile a query, the statistical distribution of that test data has to reasonably match real data.

That's why I added two users who have many more messages than the others (1001 and 1002), in this case it still uses an index but it is slower due to the higher number of messages.

However what you really want is the latest messages, hence the ORDER BY. But you have to put the ORDER BY before the LIMIT 100, in your query you put it the wrong way around, so it will pick 100 random messages then sort them. So you don't get the latest messages, only whatever 100 messages it found first, ordered by date.

If I add "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100" to the two above queries, I get the same plans with a sort added, as expected. This is not optimal if you want to display few latest messages (or only the latest message) out of many messages between these users. In this case, the index in jjanes' answer (with date added) is much better.

Before the index, these two queries result in the same plan:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE (sender,receiver) IN ((1001,1002),(1002,1001))
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE sender=1001 AND receiver=1002 OR sender=1002 AND receiver=1001
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 100;

Limit  (cost=4376.11..4376.36 rows=100 width=12) (actual time=23.011..23.019 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4376.11..4379.15 rows=1217 width=12) (actual time=23.009..23.013 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: date DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on msg  (cost=25.65..4329.59 rows=1217 width=12) (actual time=5.562..11.479 rows=100000 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (((sender = 1001) AND (receiver = 1002)) OR ((sender = 1002) AND (receiver = 1001)))
               Heap Blocks: exact=541
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=25.65..25.65 rows=1217 width=0) (actual time=5.513..5.513 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on msg_sr  (cost=0.00..20.50 rows=1207 width=0) (actual time=5.510..5.510 rows=100000 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((sender = 1001) AND (receiver = 1002))
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on msg_sr  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((sender = 1002) AND (receiver = 1001))
 Execution Time: 23.069 ms
```

With function index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON msg (least(receiver,sender), greatest(receiver, sender), date);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM msg 
WHERE least(receiver,sender)=1001 AND greatest(receiver,sender)=1002 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10;
Limit  (cost=0.43..40.79 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.045..0.054 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using msg_least_greatest_date_idx on msg  (cost=0.43..1017.47 rows=252 width=12) (actual time=0.043..0.049 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((LEAST(receiver, sender) = 1001) AND (GREATEST(receiver, sender) = 1002))
 Execution Time: 0.095 ms
```

That's 100 microseconds, or 380 times faster than without the index, because these example users have lots of messages between them.

Adding the date column is essential as it allows to skip the sort, as rows for messages between these two users are already sorted by date in the index.

This only works because using least and greatest allows to create a unique "key" for messages between two users. So we don't have the AND/OR/AND condition we did, instead we have a key which is referred to by equality, and therefore directly indexable without bitmap scan, which then allows a range request on the btree index to get rows ordered by date.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown any suboptimal performance.  For all we know, that is actually the fastest way to do the query.

You could canonicalize the order of the ids and search on that canonical representation.  Something like this (ignoring your quoting which makes my eyes bleed):

```
create index on messages (least(recipient_id,sender_id), greatest(recipient_id, sender_id));

...where least(recipient_id,sender_id)=1 and greatest(recipient_id, sender_id)=15
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on `("SenderId", "RecipientID")`, then your query should be able to use an index scan. You could also rewrite the query to the more concise form

```
... WHERE ("SenderId", "RecipientId") = (15,1)
       OR ("SenderId", "RecipientId") = (1,15)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I still get a seq scan even with enable_seqscan turned off.  On  PostgreSQL 17devel-741fb0056e.

Comment: @jjanes Right, I should have checked that. Then a bitmap OR is the best choice.

Comment: I was surprised that that way of writing it gets the index usage when your `=ANY` version did not.  But I verified that it does.  But, his original way of writing it would also use that index, he just needs to create the index.  His original query with his original indexes could also get a (less efficient) bitmap plan using an BitmapOr and two BitmapAnds, but I guess the planner didn't think that that would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the current value of random_page_cost. Consider reducing the random_page_cost around ~ 1.5 to 1.9, and then rerun the query again.